# Can I use any size hard drive on any (recent) motherboard?

Tags: hard-drive, motherboard, compatibility

There are appliances (notably drive enclosures) advertizing themselves as compatible with "up to 3TB" hard drives. I am therefore wondering if I might find myself stuck with a useless [Seagate Ironwolf 10TB](https://www.seagate.com/fr/fr/internal-hard-drives/hdd/ironwolf/) drive on my medium-old, medium-crap [AsRock AM1B-ITX](https://www.asrock.com/mb/AMD/AM1B-ITX/) motherboard.

I couldn't find any indication anywhere that this would be the case, but better safe than sorry. Thanks!

Comment: You have 2 different issues here.  The enclosure and the motherboard.  The motherboard should support any size drive when connect via SATA.  Where does the enclosure come into the equation?  You will have to format it with a GPT it is too big for MBR.

Comment: The enclosures, which have some kind of board inside them, made me wary that maybe my mobo would suffer from the same issue, which is my one and only problem. If I read you correctly any sata mobo can be connected to any sata drive, period?